# Using Unity in MVC. How to Inject its dependencies elsewhere?

Tags: model-view-controller, dependency-injection, unity-container, console-application

Ive been using Unity in my MVC project for a while, succesfully injecting dependencies like this one:

```
public interface IDepartmentRepository
{
 //blah blah
} 
public class DepartmentRepository: IDepartmentRepository
{
// blah blah
}
```

into controllers and using them to do CRUD on an SQL Compact database using EF CodeFirst, also logging using NLog, and other stuff for my app.

But what if I wanted to inject those outside the MVC webapp, into a console application? It seems i'm missing something when i do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IContext, SCSMContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<ILogger, NLogLogger>();
        container.RegisterType<IDoSomething, DoSomething>();

        DoSomething foo = (DoSomething)container.Resolve<IDoSomething>();

    }
}

public interface IDoSomething
{
}

class DoSomething: IDoSomething
{
    IOrderRepository orderRepository;
    IOrderFileUploadRepository orderFileUploadRepository;
    IContext unitOfWork;
    ILogger logger;

    public DoSomething(IOrderRepository orderRepository,
                       IContext unitOfWork, 
                       ILogger logger)
    {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.logger = logger;

        logger.LogInfo("Logging from an external project!");
        orderRepository.Add(new Order() {OrderName="foo"});
        unitOfWork.CommitChanges();
        // These lines run and give no exceptions
        // But nothing gets logged or inserted

        orderRepository.GetAll();
        //Returns an empty list, when there are orders in db.
    }
}
```

}

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

ILogger and NLogLogger classes:

```
public interface ILogger
{                    
    void LogInfo(string message, params object[] args);       
    void LogWarning(string message, params object[] args);  
    void LogError(string message, Exception exception, params object[] args);
}


public class NLogLogger : ILogger
{
    private Logger _logger;

    public NLogLogger()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public void LogInfo(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger.Info(message);
    }

    public void LogWarning(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger.Warn(message);
    }

    public void LogError(string message, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        _logger.Error(message + LogUtility.BuildExceptionMessage(exception));
    }
}
```

Note: This project is a project that some other person worked on, then left.. 
I'm still figuring out how the whole thing works, sorry if I ignore some things.

The IContext and SCSMContext classes seem somewhat too profound for me to fully grasp, here they go:

**IContext:**

```
public interface IContext : IQueryableUnitOfWork
{

    IDbSet<Location> Locations { get; }
    IDbSet<Department> Departments { get; }

    IDbSet<Requisition> Requisitions { get; }
    IDbSet<RequisitionAttachment> RequisitionAttachments { get; }
    IDbSet<RequisitionItem> RequisitionItems { get; }
    IDbSet<RequisitionComment> RequisitionComments { get; }

    IDbSet<Order> Orders{ get; }
    IDbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; }
    IDbSet<OrderFileUpload> OrderFileUploads { get; }

    IDbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; }

    IDbSet<DispatchNote> DispatchNotes { get; }
    IDbSet<DispatchItem> DispatchItems { get; }

    IDbSet<LocationsInRolesForUser> LocationsInRolesForUser { get; }

}
```

**SCSMContext:**

```
public class SCSMContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, IContext
{
    #region IContext Members

    IDbSet<Order> _orders;
    public IDbSet<Order> Orders
    {
        get
        {
            if (_orders == null)
                _orders = base.Set<Order>();

            return _orders;
        }
    }

    //Other IContext definitions......

    #endregion



    #region IQueryableUnitOfWork Members

    public IDbSet<T> CreateSet<T>()
               where T : class
    {
        return base.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Attach<T>(T item)
        where T : class
    {
        //attach and set as unchanged
        base.Entry<T>(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
    }

    public void SetModified<T>(T item)
        where T : class
    {
        //this operation also attach item in object state manager
        base.Entry<T>(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void ApplyCurrentValues<T>(T original, T current)
        where T : class
    {
        //if not is attached, attach original and set current values
        base.Entry<T>(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(current);
    }

    public void CommitChanges()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void RollbackChanges()
    {
        // set all entities in change tracker 
        // as 'unchanged state'
        base.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                          .ToList()
                          .ForEach(entry => entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(string sqlQuery, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return base.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sqlQuery, parameters);
    }

    public int ExecuteCommand(string sqlCommand, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return base.Database.SqlCommand(sqlCommand, parameters);
    }

    #endregion


}
```

**Also, IQueryableUnitOfWork:** (just in case?)

```
public interface IQueryableUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, ISql
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a IDbSet instance for access to entities of the given type in the context, 
    /// the ObjectStateManager, and the underlying store. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IDbSet<T> CreateSet<T>() where T : class;

    /// <summary>
    /// Attach this item into "ObjectStateManager"
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of entity</typeparam>
    /// <param name="item">The item <</param>
    void Attach<T>(T item) where T : class;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set object as modified
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of entity</typeparam>
    /// <param name="item">The entity item to set as modifed</param>
    void SetModified<T>(T item) where T : class;

    /// <summary>
    /// Apply current values in <paramref name="original"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of entity</typeparam>
    /// <param name="original">The original entity</param>
    /// <param name="current">The current entity</param>
    void ApplyCurrentValues<T>(T original, T current) where T : class;
}
```

Sorry for the humongous post :\

Comment: What do you expect you are missing? You setup your container in the composition root of your app (Main()). You resolve the entry point to your object graph (implementation of IDoSomething), the container injects the neccessary dependencies and then you tell your root object to start working. That's it.

Comment: @SebastianWeber thats the thing. Even if I do all that, my repository + unitOfWork do nothing to my database (cant fetch or commit data), and my logger wont log. There's clearly something i'm not doing right :\

Comment: Did you create a configuration file for your logger and context? Is this file copied to your BIN-folder? Or do you configure them in code somewhere?

Comment: Apparently, they're configured in code. Please see my (somewhat large) Edit above!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I need some more clarifications: Why do you cast the result of your call to the container to `DoSomething`? You don't inject your context into the repository. I would guess that the repository needs the context in order to function. And I'm not familiar with NLog, but if it's similar to Log4Net you would need more configuration (like a dedicated section in your app.config or an explicit setup in code) to tell the framework where to log (file, database, eventlog, ...) and what logger to use (flat file logger, rolling file logger, ...) than a simple call to `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger`

Comment: You're right, I dont need to cast anything there. Changed it.  
Yes, NLog has its own NLog.config which states where to log (targets) and what to log (rules).   And, I'll look into not registering the IContext in Unity; I've been doing it since its the way its been done in this project.. also yes, the repositories need the context for them to work properly.
Note: I can log and use my repositories from the MVC project ( injecting them into my controllers) without a problem!

Comment: @seed_87 If the logger and the repository both get injected and called by `DoSomething` then I would it expect that this is an issue with the configuration of those two, not an issue with the container.